# JQuery '.load()' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to use the `jQuery` `.load()` function and I can't get it to work. I am working on a Wordpress plugin, and I'm trying to set an attribute on the `options`, based on a parameter that is passed in (more specifically, I'm trying to set the default option on the selection box).

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$("#schedule_timeslot").load(function(){
          //execute code to make changes to DOM
          //use conditional statements to figure out which DOM to adjust
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
        <select id="schedule_timeslot" name="timeslot">
            <option name="8-10" class="schedule_time" value="0" id="ts0">8am - 10am</option>
            <option name="10-12" class="schedule_time" value="1" id="ts1">10am-12pm</option>
            <option name="12-2" class="schedule_time" value="2" id="ts2" >12pm - 2pm</option>
            <option name="2-4" class="schedule_time" value="3" id="ts3">2pm - 4pm</option>
            <option name="4-6" class="schedule_time" value="4" id="ts4" >4pm - 6pm</option> 
        </select>
```

I was able to use:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert("test"); 
});
```

Can anyone tell me why the function isn't working and what I need to do to execute a function on a specific element?

Comment: Because `$("#schedule_timeslot")` is not loaded when you call it, therefore, jQuery can not select it. Even if it can select it, a `<select>` would not fire a `onload` event.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think `<select></select>` fires a load event. The `window` does and `<img />` tags do but I don't believe `<select>` nodes do.

Comment: A `select` doesn't have a load event.  You explain what you expect this to do?  Also, `load` is deprecated.

Comment: @War10ck it looks like you're right: `This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.`

Comment: @JamesMontagne I'm trying to execute a function on this specific element when the page loads.

Comment: Do it on document.ready then, selects don't have anything to load, other than the markup.

Comment: @blaine in that case you should attach your handler to the window, not the element.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete... What are you trying to do? "trying to execute a function on this specific element" doesn't tell us much to give you alternatives

Comment: the jQuery load() event is deprecated in jQuery since 1.8 - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ - use bind() or on()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<select>` elements do not fire a load event. Load events are fired on elements that are associated with URL's (which usually require a separate HTTP request to fetch the resource) such as a `<script>` tag, `<img />` tag, `<iframe>` tag, etc.

To fire an event on a `<select>`, simply target the element in a document ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#schedule_timeslot")....
});
```

or shorthand,

```
$(function () {
    $("#schedule_timeslot")...
});
```

This ensures the DOM loaded and ready and the element will be present when you target it with jQuery (provided this is loaded on the page initially and not through ajax).

**EDIT:**

To invoke a function on document ready simply define the function in a script tag or external JavaScript sheet. Inside the document ready block, call the function.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        alert("Hello, I am ready!");
    }

    $(function () {
        init();
    });
</script>
```

Document ready blocks also provide a place to apply event handlers. Since these blocks fire when the DOM is finished loading, you can be sure that any element on the page that loads with the initial page load (not through ajax) will be present.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#schedule_timeslot").on('change', function (e) {
           alert("I Changed!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

To set the default selection on the select box you would use `.val()` in jQuery. In the document ready section call `.val()` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#schedule_timeslow").val(4);
        // This will select
        // <option name="4-6" class="schedule_time" value="4" id="ts4" >
        // as the option in the select box.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants `.change()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the calling of the function? Would I just do`$("#my_id").function(){ // my code }` or what?

Comment: @Blaine I've elaborated some more on what you can do inside of document ready blocks. Let me know if you need some more clarification and I will be happy to extend it some more.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration. I added some more content to my question in the hopes of clarifying what I'm trying to do. I'm not trying to execute this code when I make a change, but rather when the selection box appears because I want to set the default selection on the selection box.